# Symfony 4 - Database connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, symfony4

- Symfony4
- PHP 7.2.19
- Ubuntu Linux 18.04.2 ( Up to date)
- MySQL 5.7.27

Its seems like I cannot get access to my database.
I do have access to phpMyAdmin with the same user & password.

I downloaded a D8 to test if it is working with this installation:
Surprisingly it works, with the same user I can set up a D8 installation.

If I download a fresh Symfony4 project the issue persists.

Its the first time I got this issue,

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:userPW@localhost:3306/db
```

This is my CLI output:

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 93:
>   An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ..

Comment: did you try to clean the cache of symfony?

Comment: Hello, yes I did.. almost every time I do changes